# Empty home directory

Tags: filesystem, home-directory

I just fixed an issue with a login loop, using this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1214356/deleted-conffiles/1214360?noredirect=1#comment2040663_1214360). So now I can log into my account again, but the home directory looks empty. I can see my old folders (Documents, Pictures, PycharmProjects etc) when I do `cd /home/tmp/ && ls`, but the folders don't appear graphically in my file system nor in /home/ when I try to list them. I tried moving them from tmp to home and I tried copying, but they remain invisible. How do I get the normal filesystem back? I'd rather not fix this by trial and error, that's why I ask it here.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with a 5.3.0-28-generic kernel on a Dell Vostro 5590 laptop (only a few months old). It's not dual booted, I removed Windows.

Cheers!

Comment: What does `whoami` show you?

Comment: @K7AAY, my username...

Comment: Which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Are you using virtualization, and if so, which package? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please do not use Add Comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gedit ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
```

It should look like this:

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

Logout and log in again. They should become visible. But make sure these folders exist in your `~/` folder. That is:

```
$ ls ~/

Desktop  Downloads  Documents  Music  Public  Pictures  Videos    Templates
```

If you do not see these folders in your user's directory, then

- create them manually
- edit `user-dirs.dirs` file
- copy files `cp -fr /home/tmp/Documents/* /home/youruser/Documents/`
- Change ownership if required: `chown -R /home/youruser/Documents`
- logout/login and check if Documents folder appeared.
- repeat for the rest folders

[Reference](https://askubuntu.com/a/86989/925971)

Comment: I get the right output of that gedit command, but the folders do not appear. The only thing in my homedirectory is examples.desktop, which, I suspect, is needed for login.

Comment: You need to ensure, those directories are present in your home folder. If no, create them.